# Sub-tick loops in functions without recursions

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

We all know that adding the `minecraft:tick` tag to a function can make the function run once every tick, but this would create a really slow loop. The question is, how to complete a loop in a single tick, without using some sort of tail-recursion (because the call stack would be really deep thus lag the game, am I right?).

The tail-recursion pattern I'm talking about is like this

```
scoreboard players set global var 0
# Do something
scoreboard players add global var 1
execute if score global var matches ..(some number) run function (this function)
```

Since someone misunderstood my question, I'm going to edit this a bit more... BTW I'm not English native speaker so some words may not be so accurate...

My goal is to complete a loop in one single tick, not running something like 40 times a second evenly.

Comment: So you want to run a function for example 40 or 1000 times in a second, but in regular intervals? That's not possible, since everything in the game runs in 20 Hz ticks. Also, I'm pretty sure stack size doesn't contribute to lag.

Comment: @FabianRöling Question updated.

Comment: What do you mean with a "loop"? The game loop is already what a tick is. And a ticking function or a repeating command block already runs once per tick. What else do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no proper call-stack with function recursion. For example if you call a function that creates and sets a score, that score will still be set when the function is exited.

When a function is called, its commands are essentially just appended to the front of the to-do list.

For this reason, you shouldn't worry about recursion depth. And, as there are no iteration constructs, recursion is the way you'd achieve what you want.